# Использование TreeMap для подсчета количества вхождений слов

Tags: java, коллекции

Передо мной стоит задача подсчитать частоту появления слов в введенном тексте. Для хранения слов использую коллекцию `TreeMap` (для автоматической сортировки).
При поиске решения задачи листал справочник Кея Хортсманна Java SE 8:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Меня интересует строка `counts.put(word, counts.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);`.

Я попытался интерпретировать ее для своего примера, но у меня ничего не вышло.  У меня нет полного понимания происходящего, и потому все что я могу на данном этапе - дергать куски кода из разных источников и пытаться соединить их воедино.

Вот мой код:

```
package firstPackage;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer randomNumber;
        Console cons = System.console();
        Map<Integer,Word> list = new TreeMap<>();
        Random generator = new Random();
        String myText = cons.readLine();        
        for (String word : myText.split(" ")) 
        {
            randomNumber = generator.nextInt(100001);
            list.put(list.getOrDefault(0, word) + 1, word);
        }
    }

    class Word
    {
        Integer count = 0;
        String word;

        Word(Integer count, String word)
        {
            this.count = count;
            this.word = word;
        }
    }
}
```

В данном случае Eclipse в строке `list.put(list.getOrDefault(0, word) + 1, word);` пишет ошибку:

> The method getOrDefault(Object, Word) in the type Map is not applicable for the arguments (int, String).

Я не понимаю что я должен сделать чтобы ее исправить.

Как написать код `list.put(list.getOrDefault(0, word) + 1, word);` так, чтобы он был пригоден для использования в моей программе? Где я совершаю ошибку?

Comment: А зачем вы создали класс `Word`? И почему создали `Map<Integer, Word>`, а не `Map<String, Integer`> как в примере? Называть переменную типа `Map` как `list` (список) - неудачное решение.

Comment: @Regent
Создал класс Word что бы хранить в нем само слово и кол-во, показывающее сколько раз оно было встречено. Хортсманн не дает контекста той строке кода, и поэтому я не понимаю что он подразумевает. Я не понимаю где у него ключ, где слово, а где счетчик. В Map нужно вложить ключ и значение, верно? Ключ не может показывать сколько раз слово было встречено, значит кол-во должно хранится в значении. Я рассуждал именно таким образом. По-вашему класс Word не нужен?

Comment: Да, `Word` здесь излишне, так как пары "слово - количество" у вас (и у Хортсманна) хранятся в виде `Map`, а не в виде доп. класса. Вопрос в том, чего вы вообще хотите добиться. У вас, например, ещё и `Random` в коде зачем-то присутствует. Вы просто хотите посчитать количество слов из строки с консоли или что-то другое?

Comment: Класс Word не нужен, слово должно храниться в Map<String,Integer>, и там же должно храниться число соответствующее этому слову .

Comment: @Regent 
Я хочу посчитать частоту, с которой встречается каждое слово. С помощью Random я создаю ключи. Господин Хортсманн во всех примерах пишет их вручную.

Comment: @АлексейФедотов какие ключи, и имеют ли они вообще отношение к вопросу?

Comment: моя HashMap хранит в себе пары Ключ-Значение. О том как и откуда берутся ключи в книге не сказано ни слова. Я предполагаю что я их должен создавать сам. 
В примере Map<String, Integer>. Где здесь ключ, где само слово, и где счетчик, показывающий сколько раз было встречено слово?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посчитать количество вхождений каждого слова из введённой из консоли строки можно так:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = scanner.nextLine();
Map<String, Integer> wordToCount = new TreeMap<>();
for (String word : text.split(" ")) 
{
    wordToCount.put(word, wordToCount.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);
}
System.out.println(wordToCount);
```

`wordToCount` (у вас - `list`, у Хортсманна - `counts`) - это `TreeMap<String, Integer>`. То есть ключом выступает `String` (само слово), а значением - `Integer` (количество вхождений слова).

`wordToCount.getOrDefault(word, 0)` выдаёт либо сохранённое в `wordToCount` количество вхождений слова `word`, либо `0`, если слова `word` в `wordToCount` ещё нет.
После чего к полученному значению (числу) добавляется единица и результат записывается в `wordToCount` с ключом `word`.

Эту строку можно расписать так:

```
int oldCount = wordToCount.getOrDefault(word, 0);
int newCount = oldCount + 1;
wordToCount.put(word, newCount);
```